# Not-an-answer flag disputed by the author himself

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-flag

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1294004/45937) (currently deleted, so 10K only). I flagged it as not an answer, and was disputed by the author himself!

I wonder if its wise to let the author himself be the judge to a flagged answer. Will such decisions be revised by someone who has rights to do it or is it final?

**EDIT**: I know the author of that answer himself may read this, please don't take it as an offence. I am just clarifying a doubt, pointing out a possible flaw in the software.

Comment: I started out liking contest problems because, at least, they were not homework. Over time, i have come to realize that they are poorly documented, there is no reasonable relationship to be expected between the training of the person asking and the content of the question, finally a single number incorrectly typed may take a reasonable problem into a problem that simply cannot be solved: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16341/on-polynomials-dividing-exponentials

Comment: @WillJagy, we had one such earlier today, where many of us spend nearly am hour on it just to see that OP missed a $\sqrt x$ which reduced the problem to a few seconds business!

Comment: Jesse, yes, that is about the size of it. As to your theme of the OP disputing things, I generally feel that too much weight is given to what the OP wants, as well as the judgment of the OP on what makes a useful/correct answer. If they know so much, why do they need to ask the question of us? I often answer the question that ought to have been asked; I admit, this is rarely popular.

Comment: @WillJagy, it was actually a misunderstanding in my case, please see the comments to the answer ArthurFischer gave! Also, in my case, it was not the OP, someone else answered and refused to delete.

Comment: By the way, that answer _should not_ have been flagged as "not an answer", since it is clearly an _attempt_ to answer the question. It fails in that attempt because the answerer misunderstood the question, but that's what downvotes are for, not flags. Not-an-answer flags are for when someone uses the answer box for something that they don't _intend_ to be an answer to the question

Comment: @HenningMakholm point noted! I didn't know that! Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your not-an-answer flag sent the post into the low-quality review queue. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/418107) is a link to the specific review (since the answer is deleted, I'm not exactly sure what you'll see). Since three users said the post "Looks OK" compared to one "Recommend Deletion", your flag was disputed (see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20145) for a bit of information about this recent change.). In particular, the owner of the post had nothing to do with your flag being disputed.

To learn more about disputed flags, you can check [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), in particular,

- [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/214632)

Comment: Oh well, misread my flagging queue! I felt it said "disputed" --(author), actually "--author" was in previous line! My bad! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I over analysed the situation, in light of the fact that I was once allowed into edit queue (I still do not have the rights to do it) of my own answer.

Comment: @JessePFrancis No problem. The nature of how and why flags are disputed/declined is pretty arcane and not very well documented. And it can all be a bit confusing until you get the hang of it.

Comment: I think some document/question explaining the same will help avoid a lot of similar questions like mine (I don't know if there is one already)

Comment: @JessePFrancis Consider [this search on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags+faq). Meta.StackExchange is the place where platform-wide features and questions are discussed.

Comment: @Lord_Far in, ArthurFischer has already added that info to his post! Thank you anyway!